# SQL QUERY with combination

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i HAVE A TABLE WITH FOLLOWING STRUCTURE in oracle 10g

```
VCHRNO DEBITCODE CREDITCODE  AMOUNT DATE
JV1      BA1151   0            100
JV1      BA1152   0            100
JV1       0      BL1065        100 
JV1       0      BL1066        100
```

Above is an example format. We have different debit and credit fields. So the main purpose of mine is to find how many JV's have the following combination of credit and debit

```
Credit with BA1151   and debit BL1065 or combination of both
credit   - BA1151   and    BA1152       debit -BL1065  ,BL1066
```

Only few JVs have the above credit and debit code. Others who do not have these combination should be omitted      . please suggest a query

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Also, post current and expected output.

Comment: Oracle <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Well, the result is *no rows selected* as far as these sample data is concerned. No row satisfies such a condition. Did you mix credit and debit codes? Also, I don't understand what your 2nd condition means. Could you fix sample data, fix conditions and post what result you expect out of that?